# Subquery returned more than 1 value error for individual column filtering

Tags: sql-server, subquery, filtering

I have two columns [2014 seats] and [2015 seats], I need the values only for the month of June 2015 (never mind the names of the columns, the values can be null), but the remaining columns needed to be taken for the whole year (2014). I tried out the following query and it shoots the subquery returned more than 1 value error. Your help is much appreciated, thank you!

```
select 
    [First Name], [Last Name],
    (select [2014 Seats]
     from dbo.Combined2
     where [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30') as Seats_2014,
    (select [2015 Seats]   
     from dbo.Combined2
     where [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30') as Seats_2015
from 
    dbo.Combined2 
where 
    Region = 'NAM' and 
    [FTE Status] = 'Active' and 
    [ReportMonth2] between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This query just doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the column values for 2014 seats and 2015 seats only for the month of june 2015 but the remaining columns need to be considered for the whole year 2014..Table name is Combined2

Comment: You didn't provide anywhere near enough information for much more than a guess. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to do but here is a shot in the dark.

```
select [First Name]
    ,[Last Name]
from dbo.Combined2 
cross apply 
(
    select [2014 Seats]
    from dbo.Combined2
    WHERE [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30'
)as Seats_2014
cross apply
(
    select [2015 Seats]   
    from dbo.Combined2
    WHERE [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30'
)as Seats_2015
where Region='NAM' 
    and [FTE Status]='Active' 
    and [ReportMonth2] between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
```

Comment: Hi Sean,thanks for the query,I have edited the question so that it can be understood more clearly.Please let me know which part of the question you dint understand,I tried the above query and it only returns one value multiple times

Answer (score 1):

In the query you informed us, the two subquerys is getting lots of values to list in a single row, ex:

`N° First Name   Last Name  Seats 2014              Seats 2015
1  John         Paul       All seats of John Paul  All seats of John Paul
2  Paul         John       All seats of Paul John  All seats of Paul John`

This is what you want ?

EDITED AGAIN:

```
select 
  [First Name], [Last Name],
  Seats_2014 = STUFF((
                       select ', ' + [2014 Seats]
                       from dbo.Combined2
                       where [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30'
                       ORDER BY [2014 Seats]
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
  Seats_2015 = STUFF((
                       select ', ' + [2015 Seats] 
                       from dbo.Combined2
                       where [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30'
                       ORDER BY [2015 Seats] 
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
from 
  dbo.Combined2 
where 
  Region = 'NAM' and 
  [FTE Status] = 'Active' and 
  [ReportMonth2] between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
```

Explanations:

```
  Seats_2014 = STUFF((
  -- Stuff is used to remove the first ', ' from the result
                       select N', ' + [2014 Seats]
  -- N is the string declaration for nvarchar (used to prevent problems with strange characters) and ', ' come before each Seat
                       from dbo.Combined2
                       where [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30'
                       ORDER BY [2014 Seats]
               FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N''),
  --for xml path do the concatenation trick, the 1,2 is how many characters will be removed from tab (', '), in this casse one ',' and one ' ' and trade for N''
```

Also see that this line is the same for 2014 and 2015, this is right ?

`where [ReportMonth2] between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30'`

Comment: I dont know if that will work, but give it a try, and see this link for more information http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation

Comment: Thanks Tiago,let me try and get back to you

Comment: Tried your query Tiago,It shots me this error "Error converting data type nvarchar to float."..Not sure why

Comment: I think the N'' in this query means the type of data, try google it (SQL Server FOR XML PATH) if u can, i will help soon as i can.

Comment: Try again without the N